# Reflection in Java

Tags: java, class, object, reflection, types

I am new to reflection in java and I thought that since I provided the arguments to the EnemyShip constructor that will be preserved. And After changing just the name of the ship, only that will be changed. However, I got wentworth is travelling at 0 instead of what I expected : wentworth is travelling at at 3242

Last line of code should in reflectionTest be main focus

I have 2 classes:

```
package com.reflectionapi.demo;

import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class reflectionTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Class shipClass = EnemyShip.class;
    int shipMod= shipClass.getModifiers();
    String shipModStat="";

    switch(shipMod){
    case Modifier.PUBLIC: shipModStat="Public";
            break;
    case Modifier.PRIVATE: shipModStat="Private";

    }


    System.out.println(shipClass.getName()+" "+shipModStat
            );//prints class of ship




    Method[] methods = shipClass.getMethods();


    Class[] parameters;


    for (Method method: methods){
        String methodName = method.getName();
        parameters= method.getParameterTypes();// assign method parameters to paramters array

        if (methodName.startsWith("get"))
                    System.out.println(methodName+" is a Getter Method "+
                            "it returns "+ method.getReturnType()+"\n");    

        else 
            if (methodName.startsWith("set"))

                    for (Class param: parameters){
                System.out.println(methodName+" is a Setter Method and "+
                "takes parameters "+ param.getName()+"\n");
                    }

        }

    Class superClass = shipClass.getSuperclass();
    System.out.println(shipClass+" is a subclass of "+ superClass.getName()+"\n");


    Constructor[] constructors = shipClass.getConstructors();   
    //Constructor constructors = shipClass.getConstructor(new Class[] {EnemyShip.class} ); not iterable

    Object constructorItem =null;

    for (Constructor construct: constructors){
        System.out.println(construct);

    }


    try {
         constructorItem= shipClass.getConstructor(String.class , int.class ).newInstance("XT-1800", 5000);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    EnemyShip ship = new EnemyShip("Carl", 3242);

    ship.setName("Wentworth");
    //ship.setSpeed(1230420);

    System.out.println(ship.getName()+
            " is travelling at "+
            ship.getSpeed());



    }

}
```

Second class

```
 package com.reflectionapi.demo;

 public class EnemyShip {



public EnemyShip (String s, int m){// s= name m= speed
    /*
    name =s;
    speed=m;
 try later */

    System.out.println(s+
             " is travelling at :"+ m);
}

public EnemyShip (String s, int m, double j){// s= name m= speed

    System.out.println(s+
             " is travelling at :"+ m);
}


public String getName (){   
    return name ;
}

public void setName(String s){

    name =s;
}

public void setSpeed(int s){

    speed =s;
}

public int getSpeed(){
    return speed;
}

    private String name =""; 
    private int speed=0;

}
```

Comment: Your EnemyShip constructors aren't doing what they should be doing: they don't set the respective fields. If they don't do this, how do you expect the fields to be changed by calling the constructor?

Comment: The only way I have found the 0 to change is when I explicitly call setSpeed();

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels But I do provide the args needed for object construction

Comment: ??? arguments mean nothing if you don't do anything with them. You've got what looks like correct code commented out -- why?

Comment: Yeah I know thats's what would work, but my logic was that if I changed just the name I don't have to change the speed and speed will be preserved and returned on the next call

Comment: What? Why would speed be "preserved" when it is never stored in the first place? Your logic escapes me.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: answered as a community wiki

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: What was solved? How? This question seems to be little more than Java 101 and has nothing to do with reflection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131988/discussion-between-battledrum-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).

Answer (score 1):

Your EnemyShip constructors do nothing -- they don't set the fields that they are supposed to set, and so calling them, *with correct arguments* is meaningless. You have to use them to either set the EnemyShip fields or if there is a super Ship class, then set its field via a super constructor call.

So uncomment the commented code from this:

```
public EnemyShip (String s, int m){// s= name m= speed
    /*
    name =s;
    speed=m;
 try later */
}
```

to this:

```
public EnemyShip (String s, int m){
    name =s;
    speed=m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Enemyship is doing nothing,You have to assign the values as

```
name=s;
speed=m;
```

Hope it helps.